# spring-integration-sftp v6.1.2 throws NoSuchMethodError org.apache.sshd.client.future.ConnectFuture.verify(java.time.Duration)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Upgraded sshd-sftp from 2.9.2 to 2.10.0 and test failed with exception below.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object org.apache.sshd.client.future.ConnectFuture.verify(java.time.Duration)'

    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.initClientSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:316)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:282)
```

**Package dependencies [Spring boot v3.1.2]:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2</version>   
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.2</version>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion> <!-- Security Fix from 2.9.2 to 2.10.0 -->
           <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
           <artifactId>sshd-sftp</artifactId> 
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
  <artifactId>sshd-sftp</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried adding the test dependencies and same exception is raised. Shifting back to 2.9.2 with sshd-sftp works.

Comment: Have you tried look for conflicts with your other dependencies?  The other two you show here were released after sshd 2.10.0 but I think its possible that a third party library is calling an obsolete method in sshd.

Answer (score 2):

Consider to exclude just group:

```
  <exclusion> <!-- Security Fix from 2.9.2 to 2.10.0 -->
       <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
  </exclusion>
```

That `ConnectFuture.verify()` comes from the `sshd-common` which I believe is left somehow as a transitive dependency in old version. Although we didn't change that code in the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` when we had upgraded Spring Integration `6.2` to MINA `2.10.0`.

The signature of that method was changed, though:

```
default T verify(Duration timeout) throws IOException {
```

in `2.9.2` and:

```
default T verify(Duration timeout, CancelOption... options) throws IOException
```

in `2.10.0`. So, that Spring Integration version is not going to work against that new version since byte code does not match. It has to be recompiled against new version.

The problem is that according to our policy we cannot upgrade to minor version in  our point version.

According to the vulnerability description: https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-ORGAPACHESSHD-5769686, we don't need to worry about expose if we don't do MINA SFTP server. Spring Integration SFTP module is really about SFTP client. As long as you don't deal with MINA server, you are OK to stick with `2.9.2` until we release Spring Integration `6.2` this Fall.

Comment: Hi Artem -
exclusion without <artifactId>sshd-sftp</artifactId> throws an error in the pom.xml.  and without sshd-sftp it breaks the code 
 

`return new CachingSessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry>(factory)`

I guess I will wait when Spring Integration 6.2 is release to upgrade sshd-sftp. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for confirmation that exclusion doesn’t work ! Can, please, confirm that indeed are affected by that MINA vulnerability or this just was a false positive by some scanner report?